# Uncertain about some instructions in disassembly of data section

Tags: c, assembly, gnu-assembler

I wrote the following assembly program and I am unsure about the meaning of some of the compiled instructions, and the syntax in which it is presented by `objdump`.

Compiled with gcc version 4.4.3, linux kernel version 2.6.32-21

hello.S:

```
.global _start
.global main

.section .text

_start:
    call main

    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

main:
    // Print "Hello World" to the screen
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $hello, %ecx
    movl $13, %edx
    int $0x80

    // Exit programme with return value 0
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80

.section .data
    hello: .string "Hello world!\n"
```

And compiled with command

```
gcc -nostdlib hello.S -o hello
```

Generates the following instructions, in particular under the `.data` section: `gs`, `insb`, and `outsl`; What is the purpose of these instructions?

Disassembly of section .data:

```
080490ec <hello>:
 80490ec:   48                      dec    %eax
 80490ed:   65                      gs
 80490ee:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
 80490ef:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
 80490f0:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
 80490f1:   20 77 6f                and    %dh,0x6f(%edi)
 80490f4:   72 6c                   jb     8049162 <_end+0x66>
 80490f6:   64 21 0a                and    %ecx,%fs:(%edx)
```

Also, syntax such as `%ds:(%esi),(%dx)` - what does this mean?

Comment: Those instructions are an artifact.  Look at the hex values .. they spell out `Hello world`. The data section contains .. data.

Comment: ...oh yeah. Well, if they were real instructions, what would a syntax such as `insb (%dx), %es:(%edi)` mean? or `outsl %ds:(%esi),(%dx)`?

Comment: You disassembled the data section.  Those are the instructions represented by that sequence of bytes.  Running them would almost certainly make your  program crash.  `insb` is the byte-operand form of `INS` (Input String from IO port):  `INS m8, DX`.  The operands are implicit, just like `lodsb`, which is how that whole insn can be a single byte.  See the insn ref manual (linked from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) if you're curious what those instructions actually do.

Comment: No idea about the syntax in question but my gut feeling suggest that the parenthesis mean something like `the contents of the memory location pointed to by the address in the register`

Comment: @PeterM The parentheses around (%dx) don't actually mean anything on the in and out instructions - it isn't a de-reference. It is a curiosity of the dis-assemblers output . One that I never quite liked, although likely is an artifact of how ports work.

Comment: @PeterM: Well `in`/`out` instructions are a special case of the `(mem)` syntax.  `%dx` isn't actually used as a memory address, but rather an i/o port number.  `insb` reads a byte from the IO port number held in DX, and stores it in memory at `(%edi)` (using `%es` as the default segment), and increments `%edi` by one.  The `and` at the end has a segment-override prefix, and `%fs:(%edx)` is the usual AT&T syntax for that.  (like `and fs:[edx], ecx` in Intel/NASM)

Comment: In Intel syntax, there aren't `[]` around the register holding the I/O port number.

Comment: The logic is that plain register means the register itself.  `(%dx)` means some sort of addressing, in this case in the i/o address space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of an education

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to not get inapt disassembly of section `.data`, don't use `objdump` option

- `-D`, `--disassemble-all`    Display assembler contents of all sections

but rather

- `-d`, `--disassemble`        Display assembler contents of executable sections

and in addition

- `-s`, `--full-contents`      Display the full contents of all sections requested

to get a dump of the data:

```
Contents of section .data:
 80490a8 48656c6c 6f20776f 726c6421 0a00      Hello world!..
```